# Exporting an Adobe-XD layout to Flutter

Tags: flutter, export, code-generation, adobe-xd

I'm trying to export a very basic `XD layout` to a Flutter project.

I'm using **two component instances**, drag-and-dropped from the `Material Design light theme UI kit` in library.

After exporting it, I get **the following error** for both instances:

> *"Master component could not be found"*.

When trying to reach the master component for either instance (pressing `ctrl-shift-K)`, nothing happens. What should I do to export this layout to Flutter?
It seems to me that you can't use a UI kit widget (at least not out of the box). Is it correct?

Comment: Have you tried uncheck the prototype interaction and ungrouping elements before exporting your widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can use a UI kit widget out of the box, but you can use the underlying widget. In your case, you would use the MaterialButton widget.